# Can you turn off the light bar detection feedback?

Tags: ps4, thief

In Thief on Playstation 4, the controller's light bar lights up heavily when the player moves into light. I find this very annoying. Is there any way to turn off this feedback?

I know that the controller light itself can not be turned off completely and I don't want to do that, but the feedback light of the game is much brighter than the normal light. I just want to turn off the permanent light changes.

Comment: Have you tried disabling the light UI in the game's options menu? It's in the same section where you toggle the display of navigation prompts and markers and the like. Although I suspect this would turn off the globe both in the on-screen UI and the controller, which maybe is not what you want...

Comment: Yes, I've tried that, but it just turns off the globe, the controller reaction stays the same. Thanks for the idea anyway :) 
I ended up just putting some carton on the light bar. I don't think it can be turned off.